# How do I run stats on a data set organized by bins?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, dataset

I have a problem I am working on and I have data set up in the following way:

I wanted to test in flowers change their bloom size given the time of day, so I sampled random flowers in the morning and in the evening, measuring the diameter of their bloom.  These measurements were separated into size bins, like <3cm, 4-6cm, 7-9cm, etc.

I am not sure how to run this data since each flower was not sampled at morning and evening, it was a different flower each time....Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are they the same species and same geographic area?

Comment: Yes they are the same species and in the same area.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a random sample of the same species from the same area, it looks like you can make a valid conclusion about the behavior of this flower in morning and evening. Since they are all organized in bins, you can make histograms to see if there is a visual difference in means, percentiles, or what kind of distribution they best fit. Then, find a statistical test that helps you test a hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use ordinal logistic regression with the dependent variable being size and the independent variable being time of day.